# print svg with dash lines by chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I encountered a problem when printing svg from the Chrome browser.

I loaded an svg file in Chrome that contained dashed lines.  When it is printed by a physical HP printer, the dashed lines become several small rectangles on the paper.

However, if it is printed into a pdf by virtual pdf printer, the dashed lines look correct. 
Other browsers, such as Firefox, do not have this problem.

The svg file is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vx371zq7ksxn9zm/dash.svg?m=

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested first printing to PDF and then printing that PDF using the HP?

Comment: yes, i have tested it. it is ok to print PDF first and then print PDF using HP printer.   The bug occurs when i print the svg using HP printer directly.